# Sending email through Delphi

Tags: delphi, email, gmail, sender

I have never worked with Delphi (my girlfriend have some experience), but there is a small tool that I want to make and I think it should be made on Delphi. After hours of searching and testing we found only this guide (http://delphi.about.com/od/indy/a/email-send-indy.htm) which doesn't work, it gives a huge error when pressing the Send email button.

I am trying to make a tool that will be distributed with my game and will allow the user to send me an email (to my Gmail) in case of a problem or for feedback. He will enter his email, attach a screenshot and fill in a comment box, doesn't need to have something else. Any help will be highly appreciated as I am stuck, thank you.

Comment: Are you using your own SMTP server to send emails from your game?

Comment: No, I want to send them through my GMail account (if its possible).

Comment: I'm not sure if GMail allows non secure access to its SMTP server

Comment: I have found some examples where it looked possible (or I just didn't understand them). Actually do I need to send the email from somewhere, I mean the user will just enter his email and some other information, do I need SMTP for that? I will not reply directly to the address in the From field, but to the email that the user entered.

Comment: You need an SMTP server if you want your own application to send the email. Alternatively, you can hope that the user has a working mail client (such as Outlook or ThunderBird) and send the email through them, though I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @iManBiglari - you don't _need_ an SMTP server for sending email.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: yes, you do.  However, you don't need *YOUR OWN* SMTP server. You can either send email through your ISP provider's SMTP server, or an online web script that uses SMTP on the server side, or you can use SMTP relaying (Indy has a `TIdSMTPRelay` component for that) to connect to each recipient's SMTP server directly. But either way, SMTP is still involved in some manner.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - what I mean is that you _could_ query MX records for the recipient and deliver the message directly to their SMTP server. Not that you _should_ do, thought.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: MX lookups are what I was referring to by SMTP relaying, and is exactly what Indy's `TIdSMTPRelay` component actually does.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a simple routine to send an email. I guess you can modify it to fit your needs:

```
procedure SendImage(const Comment, AImage: String);
var
  SMTP: TIdSMTP;
  Msg: TIdMessage;
begin
  if not FileExists(AImage) then
    Exit;
  Msg := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
  try
    Msg.From.Address := 'xxxx@gmail.com';
    Msg.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'xxxx@gmail.com';
    Msg.Body.Text := Comment;
    TIdAttachmentFile.Create(Msg.MessageParts, AImage);
    Msg.Subject := AImage;
    SMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
    try
      SMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
      SMTP.Port := 25;
      SMTP.AuthType := satDefault;
      SMTP.Username := 'xxxx@gmail.com';
      SMTP.Password := '@#$%';
      SMTP.Connect;
      SMTP.Send(Msg);
    finally
      SMTP.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Msg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

PS: Note that you have to replace `xxxx@gmail.com` with your own email address, and not the user's. You could include their email address in the body of the crash report.

Comment: AFAIK Google requires a secure connection.

Comment: @The_Fox I was afraid of that. Then, Yordan has to find another SMTP server or use SSL. I'd suggest gmx.com

Comment: `TIdSMTP` works just fine with Gmail. You simply have to attach an SSL-enabled IOHandler, such as `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, to the `TIdSMTP.IOHandler` property before calling `Connect()`. There are plenty of online articles that explain how to use Indy with Gmail.

Comment: uses IdMessage, IdAttachmentFile :)

Answer (score 5):

IMO, email is not going to work 100% of the time.  You'll be lucky to get 80%.  If you use your SMTP, firewalls and ISPs must permit it.  If you use their existing email client, you rely on proper configuration.  A typical scenario is that they use Gmail or Yahoo, and then you try to send something via "imap email already on system" and the user gets confronted with an old copy of Outlook Express or Windows Mail that they didn't even know they had, but it's "registered" with windows as the default email handler.  This gets ugly.
I recommend sending via HTTP to an app on your web page. A PHP script that records the info and image into a MySQL database.  Actually, I recommend using a bug tracking database like Mantis or FogBugz (from our patron!).  I'd check them out, and then if you like what they offer, it's fairly straightforward to submit reports via HTTP post (or email, etc.).

Comment: Take a look at [Bugzscout](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions/315/bugzscout-to-capture-errors).